# trouble invoking concurrent.futures job in parallel

Tags: python

My code is as follows.

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

for cj in self.parent_job.child_jobs:
    executor.map(cj.runCommand())
```

def runCommand(self):
     os.system(self.cmd_line)
     verifyOutputFiles()
     ...

runCommand needs to be executed for all the child_jobs in parallel. Also only one child_job can be passed to runCommand at a time.

But the runCommand gets invoked only once at a time. But I need it to be invoked for all the child jobs at the same time. Any help to achieve this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `executor.map` API: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map
You made mistake by calling function and passing it's results to `map` ;) That is why your code run once.

You need to create separate function which will be called on objects your method `runCommand` as you can't pass `lambda x: x.runCommand()` (lambda in general) as argument to `executor.map`.

```
def runCommand(cj):
    return cj.runCommand()

l = executor.map(runCommand, self.parent_job.child_jobs)
```

to wait till all task compleate you have to evaluate generator `l`. So you can do `w = list(l)` and `w` will contain results

Comment: child_jobs has the list of commands to be executed. I need to run all of them in parallel.

Comment: cj has only one child job and self.parent_job.child_jobs has the list of all child jobs. Which one will reach runCommand if we execute like executor.map(cj.runCommand, self.parent_job.child_jobs)

Comment: I'm not sure what @AndrewDalke was suggesting. I think `cj.runCommand` is bound to `cj` instance so it doesn't make sense to me. I think what I posted should work - @user2194611 did you tried it?

Comment: I was mistaken. Thanks for the correction, @kkonrad. I've removed my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks @kkonrad. Your answer works. Now I've the code   executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)                      l = executor.map(invokeRunCommand, self.parent_job.child_jobs)
w = list(l)
executor.shutdown(wait="True")  There are 12 child jobs. All 12 are getting started. But 2 jobs are never getting ended. Need help to resolve this.

Comment: First of all 'executor.shutdown(wait=True)' but probably this won't change a thing. As you are having 10 processes you can execute only 10 at the same time. Futures works that way that they won't start new job if they have all processes busy. New job will be started after some running job ends. That way futures library doesn't have to implement scheduling and preempting etc. On the other side this should be more effective as processes will be less often preempted (leading to context switch) so they should execute faster. If you need processes to work concurrently than use normal processes